# How to add a method to a prototype of a generic class in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to add a method to a prototype of `PromiseLike<T>`
With `String` it is not a problem:

```
declare global {
    interface String {
        handle(): void;
    }
}

String.prototype.handle = function() {
}
```

Compiles OK

But if I try to do the same with `PromiseLike<T>`, I get a compile error `'PromiseLike' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`:

```
declare global {
    interface PromiseLike<T> {
        handle(): PromiseLike<T>;
    }
}

PromiseLike.prototype.handle = function<T>(this: T):T {
    return this;
}
```

Obviously the problem here is that `PromiseLike` is generic. How can I do this properly in typescript?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Interfaces do not exist at runtime, they are erased during compilation, so setting the value of a function on an interface is not possible. What you are probably looking for is adding the function to `Promise`. You can do this similarly:

```
declare global {
  interface Promise<T> {
      handle(): Promise<T>;
  }
}

Promise.prototype.handle = function<T>(this: Promise<T>): Promise<T> {
  return this;
}
```

Comment: I didn't realize the difference between `Promise` and `PromiseLike`. Not sure what are the consequences for me for switching to `Promise`, but I will try and hope this works.

Comment: `Promise` is the global promise constructor, so your augmenting a global object. `PromiseLike` is an interface, other libraries can provide Promisses and as long as the implement the `PromiseLike` interface thay will work with the builtin promises. You probably want to extend `Promise`, it should work :)

Comment: How come this works? Is the `this` parameter elided at runtime? I've not seen this in the TypeScript documentation, but it is really useful.

Comment: @samvv the `this` parameter is taken out during compilation, so at rumtime the function above has no parameters.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Cool, thanks for the info!

Comment: Can we do something like this for custom interface? As you mentioned interfaces are removed from compiled code, can we do by adding some class? Ex: declare global {
  interface ValueFlavours {
    changed?: number;
    getValue: () => Number;
  } 
}
({} as ValueFlavours).getValue = () => 5* this.changed;
export { }
var result = ({ changed: 10 } as ValueFlavours).getValue();
console.log(result); Here data is coming from API and we dont need class. But seems we need to add class to make getValue available everywhere. Suggestion @TitianCernicova-Dragomir

Comment: Able to achieve something like this declare global {
  interface ValueFlavours {
    changed: number;
    getValue: () => Number;
    }
}
export const changedFunc = function (this : ValueFlavours) {
    return this.changed * 2;
}

let data = { changed: 10 } as ValueFlavours;
data.getValue = changedFunc.bind(data);
var result = data.getValue();
alert(result);

Comment: @hungryMind nope, you can't do it for interfaces. Interfaces have no runtime semantics, so somthign like `({ changed: 10 } as ValueFlavours` in js will always just be `({ changed: 10 }`. You could add methods to `Object` but that will be really dangerous as those methods are available on ANY object

Comment: Anyone have a link to the docs that describes how a `this` parameter works?